# How can I calculate the mean value of positive values in each row in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I have a big numpy array of time series data. in each row I have 15 second of acceleration data. such as this:

```
a = [[1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,-4,-1,1,2,1,2,3,2,5],
     [1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,-4,-1,1,2,1,2,3,2,5],
     .
     .
     [1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,-4,-1,1,2,1,2,3,2,5]]
```

I want to calculate the average value of positive items in each row for example in this case. I want to have:

```
avg = [0.73 , 0.73, ... , 0.73]
```

I don't want to use for and loop in my implementation.

Comment: How do you get 0.73 if you are averaging only positive values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the original answer:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, -4, -1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, -4, -1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, -4, -1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5]]

b = np.array(a)

def avg(a):
    return a[a > 0].mean()

np.apply_along_axis(avg, 1, b)
```

Output:

```
array([2.2, 2.2, 2.2])
```

**EDIT:** Here's a better answer according to the comment by @user3483203:

```
np.nanmean(np.where(b>=0, b, np.nan), axis=1)
```

Comment: Please don't actually use this answer.  There are much better ways.  Use `np.nanmean(np.where(a>=0,a,np.nan),axis=1)`, which is a good answer from the duplicate

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the average of only positive elements, you can do:

```
a.clip(0).sum(1)/np.sum(a>0,1)
```

If you want to sum only positive elements and divide by total number of elements each row. You can do:

```
a.clip(0).mean(1)
```